# Ansible :run job on specific servers from inventory

Tags: ansible

I have an Inventory DBone which has around 4000 servers.
There are two groups Windows and Linux. Linux has around 2000 servers.

So in my template I kept as below:
Invnetory name: DBone
Limit: Linux

So the Ansible job will run in 2000 linux servers.
But the linux servers has many servers like a****,b****,c****,d****,e****
I need to run the job only on the a*** and b*** servers.

My playbook has:
hosts: all

How can I modify the playbook or template to run the job on a*** and b*** servers only.

Answer (score 2):

Use inventory plugin *constructed*. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory constructed
```

For example, given the list of all hosts

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
a0001
b0001
b0002
c0001
```

Create the file

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: constructed
groups:
  group_a: inventory_hostname.startswith('a')
  group_b: inventory_hostname.startswith('b')
```

Test the inventory

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory  -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    group_a:
      hosts:
        a0001: {}
    group_b:
      hosts:
        b0001: {}
        b0002: {}
    ungrouped:
      hosts:
        c0001: {}
```

Then, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: group_a
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
- hosts: group_b
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory pb.yml 

PLAY [group_a] *******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [a0001] => 
  inventory_hostname: a0001

PLAY [group_b] *******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [b0001] => 
  inventory_hostname: b0001
ok: [b0002] => 
  inventory_hostname: b0002

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
a0001: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
b0001: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
b0002: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Example of a custom inventory script**

Use a custom inventory script if you want to test a larger set of hosts. See

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t inventory script
```

For example, create the script

```py
shell> cat inventory/01-custom.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

custom_inv_conf = [{'group': 'a', 'start': 1, 'stop': 4},
                   {'group': 'b', 'start': 1, 'stop': 3},
                   {'group': 'c', 'start': 1, 'stop': 2}]


class CustomInventory(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = {}
        self.read_cli_args()

        if self.args.list:
            self.inventory = self.example_inventory()
        elif self.args.host:
            self.inventory = self.empty_inventory()
        else:
            self.inventory = self.empty_inventory()

        print(json.dumps(self.inventory))

    def example_inventory(self):
        return {
            'test_hosts': {
                'hosts': [i['group'] + str("%04d" % j)
                          for i in custom_inv_conf
                          for j in range(i['start'], i['stop'])]
            },
            '_meta': {
                'hostvars': {}
            }
        }

    def empty_inventory(self):
        return {'_meta': {'hostvars': {}}}

    def read_cli_args(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--list', action='store_true')
        parser.add_argument('--host', action='store')
        self.args = parser.parse_args()


CustomInventory()
```

Test the inventory

```bash
shell> tree inventory
inventory
├── 01-custom.py
└── 02-constructed.yml
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    group_a:
      hosts:
        a0001: {}
        a0002: {}
        a0003: {}
    group_b:
      hosts:
        b0001: {}
        b0002: {}
    test_hosts:
      hosts:
        a0001: {}
        a0002: {}
        a0003: {}
        b0001: {}
        b0002: {}
        c0001: {}
    ungrouped: {}
```

Comment: I am using Ansible Tower, how can we do this in tower?

Comment: RT.D [4. Inventory File Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-wer/3.8.6/html/administration/scm-inv-source.html#inventory-file-importing)

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your inventory file and split servers in groups (`[windows]` and `[linux]` in your example).

Then you can easily run your play on a specific group:

```yaml
- name: run play on linux servers
  hosts: linux
  tasks: ...
```

Ansible documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups

You may also consider to split your inventory file and include the subfile using the `-i` option.